# Will on having a method run in onCreate() be redundant if it is in run in onResume()?

Tags: android, android-activity

It looks like anything that occurs in onResume() wont have to be placed in onCreate since onResume() is always run after onCreate()?  I'm asking this because i have an algorithm that must be executed every time a user comes back to the main activity.  If it is already in onResume() then do i have to have it in onCreate()?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need it.  onResume is always called after onCreate so if onCreate runs so will onResume.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. `onResume` is always called after `onCreate`.

Comment: for the method super.onResume() do i need to pass in savedInstanceState?  Thats what i do for onCreate so just wondering

Comment: Yes, pass `savedInstanceState`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically so. but you need to think what pause/resume and start/stop mean for your app. Also when you are in OnCreate, the activity is not yet created, where as in onStart is it. This may have impact in properties of the activity that you seek to use/change.